# Significance of Reduced Mass System in SHM

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, harmonic-oscillator, inertial-frames, spring

I’m currently studying Simple Harmonic Motion, and there’s a topic called “Reduced Mass System”.

I pretty much understood what sir did; taking center of mass and then getting an equation in terms of spring constants and then connecting it to the time period. Cool.

The question I was wondering was, what’s the significance of it? I mean yeah the new mass is reduced, but why are we doing it, and is there there any meaningful thing I can take for my practical understanding?
I’d appreciate it if you answer in context of this chapter

I’ve attached a picture of what I’ve been taught for reference

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In physics it's common, when possible, to translate an unknown/complicated system into one that is more familiar. In this case the complicated system is the two body harmonic oscillator and the familiar system is the simple harmonic oscillator. To translate one system into the another we also have to translate all the parameters that describe the problem. So the reduced mass can be defined as 'the mass for a one body system such that it reproduces the relative motion of a two body system'. I defined it a little more general because reduced mass also appears in other two body systems.

Comment: There is more than one block[the original formula for time period in SHM answers  for just one block system]; that’s why we add a few parameters to find the new time period in terms of the new masses. The mass that we use in the formula therefore blends the two into one[which is called “reduced mass”]. Am I right in saying this?

Comment: @Natru Yes that would be a nice summary